# Is it possible to change the scope value from a view your are not in with AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, steroids

I have asked this questions many times without getting too much help on it. So I'm asking now if it's possible to change the values in a scope to a controller in a view which you are not in. Lets say, I'm in view 1 which is view1.html. The view has two buttons, button 1 and button 2. If I click on button 1 a new view will appear; view2.html. it will a bold text field for example  **{{test}}** . I want $scope.test to be "button1". When I click on button 2 I want the same view to open view2.html, but this time I want it to display "button2" and not "button1". In other words, it should be $scope.test = "button2".

The reason why I want this is to avoid creating many html pages, since I will have many different values after a while. I have tried to show and hide different bold tags, but are never able to do it. As you probably guessed, Im a noob with Angular, but I never receive a straight forward answer which is working in practice even how much I try. So please help, show me a easy example where you create two html page and one js. files, and how I can go from the first html page to the second and still show different values depending on my choice in the first view. Thanks!

**UPDATED**
Example code

view1.html

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="button1()" value="checkitems" >
  Button1
</button>
<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="button2()" value="checkitems" >
  Button2
</button>
</div>
```

indexcontroller.js

```
angular
  .module('legeApp')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic, $filter) {  

$scope.test = 'test';

 $scope.button1= function(){   

     $scope.test= 'button1';

        var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#view2.html");
        var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
        supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });
    };

 $scope.button2= function(){   

     $scope.test= 'button2';

        var view = new supersonic.ui.View("legeApp#view2.html");
        var customAnimation = supersonic.ui.animate("flipHorizontalFromLeft");
        supersonic.ui.layers.push(view, { animation: customAnimation });
    };
});
```

View2.htnml

```
<div ng-controller="IndexController">
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    Test<b>{{test}} </b>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does it mean "change from the view you are not in"? Do you want the controller for view1 to set this when view2 is displayed? Can't you set it before you change views?

Comment: even though it is not encouraged, you can use $rootscope (which is kind of equivalent of global variable) to store what button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, you can.  However, with Angular, there are so many ways to do this (services, events, `$watch`, `$rootScope` etc) that to give a good answer we would like to know exactly what you are trying to do.  It is difficult to understand what you mean by views (`ng-view` or just a template?).  Can you show a minimal working example of the problem?

Comment: I create a code example above, thanks for answering!